# Background Image is not displaying in flask

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, flask

Here is my html template `homepage.html` in `/home/saurabh/flask/templates`

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>homepage</title>
<style>
body{
        background-image:url("/home/saurabh/Pictures/599783.jpg");
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to our Homepage</h1>
    <h3>We will try to make u happy <strong>YOU</strong></h3>
    <nav>
        <a href="login.html">LOGIN</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="signup.html">SIGNUP</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my python script to render above template in `/home/saurabh/flask`

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("homepage.html")
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Everything is working fine but background-image.I have already tried using static directory but nothing worked. 
Background-image is not displaying in web browser??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a directory called: `/home/saurabh/flask/static`

Move the background image file to that directory.

Then change the line in your template file to:

```
background-image: url("{{ url_for('static', filename='599783.jpg') }}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call image from web server instead of flask default web server for your files.

> http://www.yoursitename.com/images/image.jpg

Refer [Flask Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/tutorial/static/) to solve this image issue